# RSS not listing in IE but working in FF and other browsers

Tags: php, internet-explorer, rss, feed, explorer

I have a RSS feed, for some reason I don't see any text on IE but in other browsers it's working.

The rss is starting with :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>'
<rss version="2.0">'
```

Can it be the rss or xml version? or something else, I really don't know,
IE identifies that the page is a RSS feed, but doesn't show any text.

Comment: Hey, i don't know how stackoverflow works sorry, and why there is your comment wich little char's and 1 answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the header should be like this, assuming your feed is UTF-8 encoded:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
```

You can validate your feed over here: http://validator.w3.org/feed/#validate_by_uri. For your feed there are two errors. Maybe fixing them will help.

Another point, do you send the correct Content-Type header? In PHP you can do that like this:

```
header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml");
```

Comment: Yes i got the content type right, still don't know why i don't see any text in IE

Comment: Ok i fixed it, the problem was the <channel> tag, you need to wrap the whole items with it, and close it only before you close your <rss> tag. thank you for your help and validator website.